# Etiqueta video no aparace en chrome de android

Tags: javascript, android, html5, video

Tengo un web creada, con WordPress, la cual tiene un vídeo insertado al inicio. En navegadores web el video se reproduce sin problemas pero en móviles android directamente no me aparece ni la etiqueta . He probado de mil formas..quitando poniendo atributos "controls", "mute", "autoplay" etc. Pero no consigo mostrar esta etiqueta. El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" "> 
<source src="https://www.lebecuesta.com/wp- 
 content/uploads/2018/05/lebecuesta-solo-video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

Simplemente esto en android no me aparece. No tengo ninguna media query que me lo anule ni nada.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo que compartas la parte de tu código donde se encuentra el error para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Yo ya pase por esto en mi aplicación y resulta que no es solo cosa del código de la aplicación ni de la aplicación web, sino que es por el encode del vídeo (independientemente de que sea mp4). Descargarte unos cuantos distintos y veras que unos si van y otros no.

Comment: El código que compartes tiene un error que puede hacer que no funcione nada. Tal y como está compartido, tienes una apertura de comillas después de `muted=""` que podría hacer que no se genere correctamente la etiqueta (no tendría `source` ni `src` por lo que no habría video, que parece ser el problema que comentas en otra respuesta). Ese fallo tipográfico en la etiqueta podría ser interpretado de manera diferente según el navegador causando el error que ves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo ya pase por esto en mi aplicación y resulta que no es solo cosa del código de la aplicación ni de la aplicación web, sino que es por el encode del vídeo (independientemente de que sea mp4).
 Descargarte unos cuantos distintos y veras que unos si van y otros no.

Comment: Gracias. Si era eso. He probado cambiado el encode y tienes razon. Algunos si funcionan y otros no. Gracias un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La dirección del `src=` tiene un salto de linea que no debería tener.

Si arreglando el salto de linea sigue sin funcionar prueba con el siguiente código, sin especificar el `type`:

```
<video id="video" autobuffer>
    <source src="https://www.lebecuesta.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/lebecuesta-solo-video-1.mp4">
</video>
```

Seguramente necesites un fichero JS para llamar a la función play:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

Fuente: [StackOverflow Ingles: HTML5 video element on Android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android)

Comment: Gracias por responder. El problema es que directamente, en Chrome de android, no se crea ni la etiqueta de vídeo.